# How can HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync fail with an OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, winrt-async

I'm writing code that processes data from a web service. The HTTP request itself is in an `async` method, which looks pretty much like this:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string[]>> GenericGrab(string query)
{
    var req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://example.org/" + query)) as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse res;
    try
    {
        res = (HttpWebResponse) await req.GetResponseAsync(); // BOOM!
    }
    // Boring exception handlers skipped
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    string l;
    while (true) {
        l = await read.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (l == null) break;
        // Process lines here
    }
    // Return result of processing
}
```

This method is used for various different requests against the web service. It works most of the time but seems to fail when there is a little bit more data (all responses are way below 1 MB, though). When it fails, the `GetResponseAsync` call, marked *BOOM!* in the code, results in an `OutOfMemoryException` in `mscorlib.ni.dll`. Unsurprisingly, the call stack isn't terribly informative:

```
myapp.exe!MyApp.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__1e(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50  C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.RoReportUnhandledError(System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IRestrictedErrorInfo error)    Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.ReportUnhandledError(System.Exception e)    Unknown
    System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL!System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()  Unknown
    System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL!System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeInContext(object thisObj)   Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    Unknown
    System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL!System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.Invoke()  Unknown
```

(The debugger breaks in `App.g.i.cs` which was generated by VS; the code seems to be a generic catcher for exceptions.)

I don't understand what could be going on here... the way I understand the API, the size of the response should not matter because it is being processed as a stream (using `GetResponseStream`), and the exception is thrown before that anyway.

Can anyone explain to me what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to dispose the "res" variable, and tell me if it is better. I got several gotcha in the past because I forgot to do it on HttpWebResponse objects.

Comment: It's my understanding that `res` should get disposed automatically when leaving the method's scope. Isn't that what's happening? In any case, I just tried that and unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: it does not. After it goes out of the scope, the object will be cleanup up by GC, but you don't know when.

In my case, lots of problem happened because internally HttpWebRequest tracked the number of opened response, and was blocking after a certain connection limit threshold, which made me deadlock problems. Except that, your code seems fine...

Try, I don't think it will solve something though req.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); and res.GetResponseStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: I actually tried that before posting the question... didn't help, sadly. By the way, the error usually happens the second time a request is made (but not always... if there's a bit less data, I can do dozens of requests without running into any trouble).

Comment: Last bet, have you tried setting httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering to false ?

In any case you should do ConfigureAwait(false) though, if you don't want wierd deadlock happening in prod.